# yum for fedora fails when I include the dev repo

Tags: fedora, yum

I've been having issued with yum for a while, then I disabled all the extra repositories and it started working fine. My problem is I'm trying to get dropbox installed and they don't have an rpm for fedora 8 so I have to go through the whole configure thing. This tells me I need libnautilus-extension.

But that's in the development repo which doesn't work for me. Every time I enable it I get checksum errors. Here's my fedora-development.repo :

```
[development]
name=Fedora - Development
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/$basearc
h/os/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=rawhide&arch=$basear
ch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-test file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/R
PM-GPG-KEY-fedora
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could try

```
yum clean all
```

other wise try explicitly defining the development repo see:
https://fedorahosted.org/packagedb/browser/fedora-packagedb-stable/yum.repos.d/fedora-development.repo

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "getting checksum errors" you mean having yum complain that the checksum of some downloaded files doesn't match. You're probably hitting a mirror with corrupted files. Have you tried commenting out the `mirrorlist` line and uncommenting the `baseurl` line?

However, please be aware that you run a good chance of borking your system completely if you pull in packages from rawhide if you're three major versions away (you're 8, rawhide is 11). The dependency tree pulled in will be massive, and even *if* depedency resolution won't fail complaining about missing dependencies you will have most likely a malfunctioning desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, Fedora 8 is end-of-lifed since I believe September.  Fedora 9 is about to reach EOL when Fedora 11 is released.  Is there a specific reason you are running such an old version instead of one of the current versions which both provide **libnautilus-extension.so.1** in the **nautilus-extensions** package.